# MOXY unmarshal JSON with URL in field name

Tags: java, json, moxy

I'm using Moxy to serialize a JSON based API.
Works like a charm except for one little thing:
serializing a field with a URL as fieldName doesn't work.

Here's what i'm trying to achieve:

Foo.class:

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Foo {

@XmlElement(name = "http://www.foo.bar")
private String bar;

private String foo;

@XmlElement(name = "_foo_bar")
private String fooBar;

public String getBar() {
    return bar;
}

public void setBar(String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}

public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}

public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}

public String getFooBar() {
    return fooBar;
}

public void setFooBar(String fooBar) {
    this.fooBar = fooBar;
}

}
```

Test class:

```
 package test;

 import java.io.StringReader;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;
 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
 import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
 import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
 import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

 public class TestMoxy {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\"http://www.foo.bar\":\"BAR\",\"foo\":\"FOO\",\"_foo_bar\":\"FOOBAR\"}";
    System.out.println(json);

    Foo f = unMarshal(json);
    System.out.println( f.getBar());
    System.out.println( f.getFoo());
    System.out.println( f.getFooBar());
}

public static Foo unMarshal(final String jsonString) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);      
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(jsonString);
        Foo f = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(reader),Foo.class).getValue();
        return f;
    } catch (final JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Now the output is like this:

```
{"http://www.foo.bar":"BAR","foo":"FOO","_foo_bar":"FOOBAR"}
null
FOO
FOOBAR
```

So, the question is: how to fix the unmarshalling of the first attribute ?

Comment: To use the MOXy library to unmarshall json you need to [specify the EclipseLink runtime](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/runtime001.htm#CACFEGHC): `-Djavax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`, That's not an answer, just to help investigate.

Comment: Thanks James, i forgot to mention this but i have this done via a file on the classpath 'jaxb.properties' containing: `javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in MOXy to me, I tested a few different combinations of special characters, MOXy doesn't appear to like the `:` or `\\`, those throw exceptions; where `http://`, `https://` and even `http//` seem to be ignored (that was using the dependency `org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:2.6.0`. If you really need the ability to process property names that are formed like an URL, then maybe take a look at other libraries. I like [FasterXML Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind).

I was able to get your example working pretty quickly with Jackson.:

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Foo.class:

```
package test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Foo {

    @JsonProperty(value = "http://www.foo.bar")
    private String bar;

    private String foo;

    @JsonProperty(value = "_foo_bar")
    private String fooBar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getFooBar() {
        return fooBar;
    }

    public void setFooBar(String fooBar) {
        this.fooBar = fooBar;
    }
}
```

Main/Test class

```
package test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestMoxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"http://www.foo.bar\":\"BAR\",\"foo\":\"FOO\",\"_foo_bar\":\"FOOBAR\"}";
        System.out.println(json);

        Foo f = unMarshal(json);
        System.out.println(f.getBar());
        System.out.println(f.getFoo());
        System.out.println(f.getFooBar());
    }

    public static Foo unMarshal(String jsonString) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.readValue(jsonString, Foo.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```